# Why my code is not executed after the "break" when it is outside the loop?

Tags: powershell

Why is my code not executed after the "break" when it is outside the loop?
What is the solution, please?

Here is my code:

```
$disk = 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'
    
$disk | ForEach-Object {
    if (!(Test-Path  "${_}:\"))
        {
            $ldisk=$_
            $ldisk
            break;
        }
    }
    
$ldisk
Write-Host "test"
```

Here is the output

```
PS D:\powershell> d:\powershell\ftpdisk.ps1
A
```

For me, my output must be:

```
PS D:\powershell> d:\powershell\ftpdisk.ps1
A
A
test
```

Comment: well!! Perfect! Thanks! it works!

Comment: The linked duplicate is not a very good one. I would have suggested the following, more PowerShell-idiomatic way: `$ldisk = $disk | Where-Object { ! (Test-Path "${_}:\") } | Select-Object -First 1`. Here the `Select-Object` cmdlet acts like a `break` statement as it actually breaks the pipeline when the 1st matching element has been found.

Comment: Thanks! your solution is perfect for me!